# What's the most pythonic way to count NaN's in a df agg() function?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions, nan

I want to add a column after the agg() function with the number of non-NaNs.
"len" does not distinguish between NaNs and non-Nans.
In the example bellow, I am exploring the fact that np.sum and np.mean only use non-NaNs into account. But there must be a better way of reaching the same result?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'b': [4, np.NaN, 2, 1, 6, np.NaN]})

df = df.groupby("a")['b'].agg([np.sum, np.mean, np.median, np.std, len])
df['count_non_nan'] = df['sum'] / df['mean']
df
```

Comment: Use [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) for notnull values.  Can just use `df.groupby("a")["b"].agg(['sum', 'mean', 'median', 'std', 'count'])`

Answer (score 1):

Replace np.NaN's with 0.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'b': [4, np.NaN, 2, 1, 6, np.NaN]})
df = df.replace(np.nan, 0)
df = df.groupby("a")['b'].agg([np.sum, np.mean, np.median, np.std, len])
df['count_non_nan'] = df['sum'] / df['mean']
df
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function counting non-null values in the source *Series*:

```
def countNotNull(grp):
    return grp.notnull().sum()
```

Don't be misguided by the name of *notnull* function. It takes into account
also *NaN* values.

Then include this function in your aggregation:

```
df.groupby("a")['b'].agg([np.sum, np.mean, np.median, np.std, len, countNotNull])
```

The result is:

```
   sum  mean  median       std  len  countNotNull
a                                                
0  7.0   3.5     3.5  3.535534  3.0           2.0
1  6.0   3.0     3.0  1.414214  3.0           2.0
```